# how to get response from openai for assistants

Tags: php, openai-api

I have created Assistat in openai using chat gpt-4-1106-preview model
[image]

Im trying to send some text to get response from Assistant
my code in php is as follow

```
    <?php
$api_key = $apiKey;  // Replace with your actual OpenAI API key
$assistant_id = 'asst_abc';  // Replace with your actual Assistant ID
$api_url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/assistants/' . $assistant_id . '/completions';  // Construct the correct endpoint

$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_key,
    'OpenAI-Beta: assistants=v1',
];

// Example conversation
$conversation = [
    ['role' => 'user', 'content' => 'Hello'],
];

$data = [
    'messages' => $conversation,
];

$data_json = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

$ch = curl_init($api_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

getting error
{ "error": { "message": "Invalid URL (POST /v1/assistants/asst_abc/completions)", "type": "invalid_request_error", "param": null, "code": null } }

Is there any other endpoint to use, please correct me.

Comment: I hope you followed the API docs. You need to create thread per user before accessing assistant

Answer (score 0):

using playground API endpoints i have created the flow like below and it worked for me.

```
 $api_key = 'API_KEY'; 
$assistant_id = 'ASSISTANT_ID'; // Your assistant ID
$api_url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1';
// Step 1: Create a Thread
$create_thread_url = $api_url . '/threads';
$thread_res = CreateThread($api_key,$create_thread_url);
if($thread_res)
{
    $thread_id = $thread_res;
    $message = 'Hello';
    //Step 2: Add a Message to thread using endpoint v1/threads/$thread_id/messages
    $add_message_to_thread_url = $api_url . "/threads/$thread_id/messages";
    $add_msg_res = addMessageToThread($api_key,$message,$add_message_to_thread_url);
    if($add_msg_res)
    {
        // Step 3: Run the Assistant on the Thread
        $data_ass=["assistant_id"=>"$assistant_id"];
        $run_url = $api_url . '/threads/' . $thread_id . '/runs';
        $run_id = runMessageThread($api_key,$data_ass,$run_url);
        if($run_id)
        {
            //Step 4:run steps 
            $run_steps_url = "$api_url/threads/$thread_id/runs/$run_id/steps";
            getRunSteps($api_key,$run_steps_url);           
            //Step 5: status of run
            $runs_sts_url = "$api_url/threads/$thread_id/runs/$run_id";
            $sts_chk = getRunStatus($api_key,$runs_sts_url);
            //get messages using endpoint v1/threads/{{thread_id}}/messages
            $ass_res_rul = "$api_url/threads/$thread_id/messages";
            sleep(5);
            $res = getAssResponseMessages($api_key,$ass_res_rul);
            if($res)
            {
                // Output the Assistant's response
                //echo $res;
                $data_d = json_decode($res,true);
                echo 'Assistant Response: '.$data_d['data'][0]['content'][0]['text']['value'];
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    
}

function CreateThread($api_key,$url)
{
    $response = curlAPIPost($api_key,$url);
    if($response)
    {
        $thread_data = json_decode($response, true);
        if(isset($thread_data['id']))
        {
            $thread_id = $thread_data['id'];
            //echo "THREAD ID:$thread_id<r>";
            return $thread_id;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function addMessageToThread($api_key,$message,$create_thread_url)
{
    $add_thread_data = ['role' => 'user', 'content' => $message];
    $response = curlAPIPost($api_key,$create_thread_url,$add_thread_data);
    if($response)
    {
        $msg_data = json_decode($response, true);
        if(isset($msg_data['id']))
        {
            return $msg_data['id'];
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    
}

//run message thread
function runMessageThread($api_key,$message,$run_thread_url)
{
    $response = curlAPIPost($api_key,$run_thread_url,$message);
    if($response)
    {
        //echo "runMessageThread:$response";
        $run_data = json_decode($response, true);
        if(isset($run_data['id']))
        {
            return $run_data['id'];
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function getRunSteps($api_key,$url)
{
    $response = getCurlCall($api_key,$url);
    return $response;
}

function getRunStatus($api_key,$url)
{
    $response = getCurlCall($api_key,$url);
    //echo "getRunStatus:$response<br>";
    return $response;
}

function getAssResponseMessages($api_key,$url)
{
    $response = getCurlCall($api_key,$url);
    return $response;
}


function curlAPIPost($api_key,$url,$data='')
{
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_key,
        'OpenAI-Beta: assistants=v1',
    ];
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    if($data!='')
    {
        $json_data = json_encode($data);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);  
    if($err)
    {
        echo("cURL Error #:" . $err);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return $response;
    }   
    
}

function getCurlCall($api_key,$url)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'OpenAI-Beta: assistants=v1',
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$api_key,
      ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);  
    if($err)
    {
        echo("cURL Error #:" . $err);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return $response;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the value is empty for the second run (when using the same threadid. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a better method. The OpenAI API documents are not clear on PHP and just some examples for Python. I attempted to use the standard method with gpt-turbo-3.5 model but using gpt-4.0-preview model, however nothing worked. Got the same error Invalid URL (POST /v1/assistants/asst_abc/completions.

I took the above example from vijay kumar, and had issues with the code, some places did not need json, and the order of the functions didn't work, gave me 500 error. Also the timing. sleep 5, just wasn't enough time for searching Assistant Knowledge, and finding the last message. So I added a function with loop to check after 5 sec, and then if the message is not there, wait another 5. Can tweak sleep and attempts. Some questions took 15 sec to return. Enjoy and feel free to improve and post back.

Also saving the thread ID in session, to post to the same thread. May not need. I was having issues at first and used this method.

Thanks,
David Ezzell

```
<?php
session_start(); //to store the thread ID so the same thread is used to post new messages

if( !function_exists('CreateThread') ){
function CreateThread($api_key,$url)
{
   
      $response = curlAPIPost($api_key, $url);

        // Directly check the response array
        if($response && isset($response['id'])) {
            // Return the thread ID directly from the response array
            return $response['id'];
        } else {
            // Return false if the response is not as expected
            return false;
        }
}
}

if( !function_exists('addMessageToThread') ){
function addMessageToThread($api_key,$message,$create_thread_url)
{
    $add_thread_data = ['role' => 'user', 'content' => $message];
    $response = curlAPIPost($api_key,$create_thread_url,$add_thread_data);
    if($response)
    {
        $msg_data = $response;//json_decode($response, true);
        if(isset($msg_data['id']))
        {
            return $msg_data['id'];
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    
}
}
//run message thread
if( !function_exists('runMessageThread') ){
function runMessageThread($api_key,$message,$run_thread_url)
{
    $response = curlAPIPost($api_key,$run_thread_url,$message);
    if($response)
    {
        //echo "runMessageThread:$response";
        $run_data = $response;//json_decode($response, true);
        if(isset($run_data['id']))
        {
            return $run_data['id'];
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
if( !function_exists('getRunSteps') ){
function getRunSteps($api_key,$url)
{
    $response = getCurlCall($api_key,$url);
    return $response;
}
}
if( !function_exists('getRunStatus') ){
function getRunStatus($api_key,$url)
{
    $response = getCurlCall($api_key,$url);
    //echo "getRunStatus:$response<br>";
    return $response;
}
}
if( !function_exists('getAssResponseMessages') ){
function getAssResponseMessages($api_key,$url)
{
    $response = getCurlCall($api_key,$url);
    return $response;
}
}
if( !function_exists('curlAPIPost') ){
function curlAPIPost($api_key,$url,$data='')
{
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_key,
        'OpenAI-Beta: assistants=v1',
    ];
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    if ($data != '') {
        $json_data = json_encode($data);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        error_log("cURL Error #:" . $err); // Log error to PHP error log
        return false;
    } else if ($httpcode >= 400) {
        error_log("HTTP Error #:" . $httpcode . " Response: " . $response); // Log HTTP errors
        return false;
    } else {
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }

    
}
}
if( !function_exists('getCurlCall') ){
function getCurlCall($api_key,$url)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'OpenAI-Beta: assistants=v1',
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$api_key,
      ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);  
    if($err)
    {
        echo("cURL Error #:" . $err);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return $response;
    }   
}  
}


if( !function_exists('getChatGPTMessage')){
  function getChatGPTMessage($api_key,$ass_res_rul,$lastUserMessageId){ 
 $maxAttempts = 5;
$attempts = 0;
$foundResponse = false;

$matchingAssistantResponse = '';
  $userMessageTimestamp = null;
$assistantResponse = "";

    if($lastUserMessageId && $api_key && $ass_res_rul){
  //$data_d = json_decode($res, true);
    
    
// Step 1: Find Your Message and Its Timestamp

    

while (!$foundResponse && $attempts < $maxAttempts) {//loop through and get last message
    sleep(5); // Wait for 5 seconds before checking for a response


    $Assmessages = getAssResponseMessages($api_key, $ass_res_rul);
$data_d = json_decode($Assmessages, true);
    $messages = $data_d['data'];
    
    if(!$userMessageTimestamp){
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
    if ($message['id'] === $lastUserMessageId) {
        $userMessageTimestamp = $message['created_at'];//get your message time
        break; // Stop the loop once your message is found
    }
}
      
    }
    
// Step 2: Search for the Next Assistant Message
if ($userMessageTimestamp !== null) {
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        if ($message['role'] === 'assistant' && $message['created_at'] > $userMessageTimestamp) {//get assistant message after your time
         
            $assistantResponse = $message['content'][0]['text']['value'] ?? '';
          
            break;
        }
    }
}  
    
    if($assistantResponse!=""){
        $foundResponse = true;
          
        }
    

    $attempts++;
}
    }

if ($foundResponse) {
    return $assistantResponse;
} else {
    return "";
}
 
}
}
if( !function_exists('convertUrlsToLinks')){
function convertUrlsToLinks($text) {
    // Improved pattern to exclude certain punctuation at the end of a URL
    $urlPattern = '/(http[s]?:\/\/[^\s]+[\w\/])(?=[,.。、\s】\)]|\z)/i';
    $replacement = '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>';
    return preg_replace($urlPattern, $replacement, $text);
}
}

//**********************************************************************************************************************
if( !function_exists('getChatGPTResponse')){
   
   function getChatGPTResponse($message) {
   $api_key = 'YOUR API KEY'; // Replace with your actual API key

  $assistant_id= 'YOUR ASSISTANT ID FROM OPENAI API'; // Your Assistant ID

   $api_url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1';
       
// Step 1: Create a Thread
$create_thread_url = $api_url . '/threads';
       
       
if (!isset($_SESSION['thread_res']) || $_SESSION['thread_res']=="") {
    // Create a new thread only if we don't have an active thread ID stored in the session
    $thread_res = CreateThread($api_key, $create_thread_url);
    $_SESSION['thread_res'] = $thread_res; // Store the new thread ID in the session
  
} else {
    // Use the existing thread ID from the session
    $thread_res = $_SESSION['thread_res'];
 
}
  
  if($thread_res)
{
  //echo ": thread created";
    $thread_id = $thread_res;
   // $message = 'Hello';
    //Step 2: Add a Message to thread using endpoint v1/threads/$thread_id/messages
    $add_message_to_thread_url = $api_url . "/threads/$thread_id/messages";
    $add_msg_res = addMessageToThread($api_key,$message,$add_message_to_thread_url);
    if($add_msg_res)
    {
        // Step 3: Run the Assistant on the Thread
        $data_ass=["assistant_id"=>"$assistant_id"];
        $run_url = $api_url . '/threads/' . $thread_id . '/runs';
        $run_id = runMessageThread($api_key,$data_ass,$run_url);
        if($run_id)
        {
            //Step 4:run steps 
            $run_steps_url = "$api_url/threads/$thread_id/runs/$run_id/steps";
            getRunSteps($api_key,$run_steps_url);           
            //Step 5: status of run
            $runs_sts_url = "$api_url/threads/$thread_id/runs/$run_id";
            $sts_chk = getRunStatus($api_key,$runs_sts_url);
            //get messages using endpoint v1/threads/{{thread_id}}/messages
            $ass_res_rul = "$api_url/threads/$thread_id/messages";
            
         
             $assistantResponse = getChatGPTMessage($api_key,$ass_res_rul,$add_msg_res);             

                 if($assistantResponse==""){//try one more time to get last message.
                     $assistantResponse = getChatGPTMessage($api_key,$ass_res_rul,$add_msg_res);     
 
                 }
          
        }
    }
}

       if($assistantResponse!=""){
       echo convertUrlsToLinks($assistantResponse);
       }else{
          echo "Seems to be a delay in response. Please try again, or try back later."; 
       }
   
}
}
//*********************************************
// Handling AJAX request for POST So from HTML, you have an input field, and submit, Use JQuey / Ajax to post message
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $userInput = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $response = getChatGPTResponse($userInput);
    echo $response;
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).